# How to write a block of a real code (and not pseudo-code) in Latex?

Tags: formatting, algorithms, code, algorithmic

I want to write the following code in `latex`, such that in `pdf`, we see the same **format of writing** (**except** background color and font colors). However, by `algorithmic`, output format is different. Is there any other way to write a code (and **not** pseudo-code) to see an output similar to the following code (**Please do not consider the colors and fonts**).

[image]

Comment: There are packages which handle different programming languages; on the top of my mind `listings` and `minted`. Of course, if you don't care for automatic highlighting of syntax, you can just use the `verbatim` environment.

Comment: What is "pseudo-code", and what exactly do you want to achieve by "same format of writing"? Do you want the font to be monospaced? Do you want to have the correct indenting? Do you care about the bolding (or otherwise highlighting) of key words, do you insist to **never** use highlighting or are you fine if it is convenient?

Comment: @user496634 In fact, I got my answer by comment of @campa. There is also a `Solidity language` package for `listings` HERE: [link](https://github.com/s-tikhomirov/solidity-latex-highlighting)

Answer (score 2):

According to the comment of User `campa`, I found my answer in [this repository](https://github.com/s-tikhomirov/solidity-latex-highlighting) where there is a specific package for `listings` specialized for `Solidity programming language`. In fact for most of the programming languages there is a customized package. Most practical information exists [HERE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings).

In my case, where the language is `Solidity`, there is a specific package for `listings` [HERE](https://github.com/s-tikhomirov/solidity-latex-highlighting).